# Need to provide dynamic file from azure blob to the any data activitiy in azure data factory, please share some link

Tags: file, dynamic, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, dataflowtask

Created intergrationruntime, adf and trying to transform blob csv file to oracle table.  Blob storage will receive new csv file for every one hour.
prabhakar.thati@gmail.com

I saw few videos but not able to get it. APpreciate anyone can help

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am not sure where exactly I need to write code/script to provide dynamic file in the source settings.

Comment: Will the file path be dynamic or only the file name?

Comment: Hi Aswin, only file name changes, path is fixed right now. Thank you

Comment: @Aswin - please share your email address, I need some support on Time bound task on azure blob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Storage event triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory#create-a-trigger-with-ui) to achieve your requirement. You can give the file name dynamically by using the trigger parameter `@triggerBody().fileName`.

First create string parameter in the pipeline.

[image]

Now create a storage event trigger and give the container name and folder path of the file in the trigger like below. Here my file is of csv type, you can give your file type.

[image]

Click on continue and at end of the trigger creation, it will ask to provide the value for the parameter of the pipeline and here give the trigger parameter `@triggerBody().fileName` like below.

[image]

Click on ok and trigger will be created. Now we need to use this parameter for the file name of the source dataset. For that create a dataset parameter and give it in the file name like below.

[image]

Give your folder path and use dataset parameter for the file name.

[image]

Use [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory) and give the above dataset for the source of the copy activity and here give the pipeline parameter `@pipeline().parameters.filename` for the dataset parameter like below.

[image]

Give your Oracle table dataset in the sink of the copy activity. If your target table is same for every file, then just give the table name. But if your target table is different for every file, then you need to make sure that correct table will be given for the correct file.

You need to ensure that **you publish the pipeline and trigger** before the usage.

This storage event trigger will trigger the pipeline whenever any new file uploaded or modified in the given location of the storage account and it will give the filename of that file dynamically to the copy activity and file will be copied to the destination.

Comment: please share your email address, i have some urgent task.